# Create-react-app dependency version issues

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am trying to create a basic react app using the command:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

At work we use JFrog Artifactory to manage our npm packages. When trying to use the above command, I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - GET https://artifactory.XYZ.domain:443/artifactory/api/npm/npm-main/ansi-regex/-/ansi-regex-4.1.0.tgz
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.
npm ERR! 403
npm ERR! 403 It was specified as a dependency of 'wrap-ansi'
```

Sure enough, when I look in Artifactory I can see that v4.0.1 is blocked due to a security vulnerability. What are my options here please? Is it possible to somehow force create-react-to instead use a later version without the vulnerability (looks like v5.0.1 is fine)?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
npm config set registry <path/to/artifactory>

///create your react project:- npm create-react-app myapp

//then revert to older config if you want to by 

npm config delete registry
```

let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks for the help. My registry is always set to Artifactory (it has to be to use npm packages with our given setup) so afraid this isn't the solution! The problem, I think, is that Artifactory is blocking one of the dependencies due to a security vulnerability.